# Explicitly describe colimits in $\mathsf{Set}$

Tags: category-theory

I just started learning category theory a couple months ago. In my understanding, there is a nice fact about the category of sets that one can explicitly describe limits. If $F:J \to \mathsf{Set}$ is a diagram, then $\lim F$ is just the set $\mathscr{S}$ of all cones on $F$ over the singleton set $\{*\}$ (provided that the cones form a set). This is because a cone over a set $S$ is nothing other than a cone over each $s\in S$, since elements in a set have no relations. Therefore there exists a unique morphism of cones $S \to \mathscr{S}$.

I've been trying to formulate a dual statement. Is there a convenient way to describe the colimit of a diagram in $\mathsf{Set}$?

Comment: [This link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_(category_theory)#Colimits) might be helpful to you. Dualized your statement may gives the description of the colimit.

Comment: @tetori Thanks for the link. So far I've been unsuccessful at dualizing it.

Comment: Not everything can be dualised. After all, $\mathbf{Set}^\mathrm{op}$ is very far from $\mathbf{Set}$.

Comment: Just in case you're not familiar with it, if we appeal to the theorem that we can write a colimit as a coequalizer of coproducts, then the colimit is the disjoint union of the objects, modulo the equivalence relation *generated by* $x \equiv F(f)(x)$ for any $x \in F(X)$ and $f : X \to Y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not as easy to see, but the following is true:

> Let $X : \mathcal{J} \to \mathbf{Set}$ be a diagram and let $\mathbf{El} (X)$ be the category defined below:
>
> - The objects are pairs $(j, x)$ where $j$ is an object in $\mathcal{J}$ and $x$ is an element of $X j$.
> - The morphisms $(j, x) \to (k, y)$ are morphisms $f : j \to k$ in $\mathcal{J}$ such that $(X f) (x) = y$.
> - Composition and identities are inherited from $\mathcal{J}$.
>
> Then $\varinjlim_\mathcal{J} X$ can be identified with the set of connected components of $\mathbf{El} (X)$. (Two objects in a category if there is a zigzag of arrows connecting them.)

Comment: I think this is almost literally the the description as the disjoint union of the objects modulo the equivalence relation generated by the arrows, just with some extra structure thrown in.

Comment: Sure, that's one way of looking at it.